# How to test unhandled rejection and handled rejection in Jest JS

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a class, where I want to catch rejection errors.

```
export class Logger {

  constructor () {
  this.registerHooks()
 }
 registerHooks() {
    window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      var reason = e.detail.reason;
      (reason)
console.log(
    });

    window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      var promise = e.detail.promise;
      this.warn(e)
    });
  }
```

How could I test this 2 cases with help of Jest?..

Comment: Why do you want to use a `class` if you want to catch exceptions globally?

Comment: @Bergi this class will be imported in the whole project and is responsible for catching the errors

Comment: So, a singleton by definition. You don't need a `class` to do that, a plain object literal will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I will describe an example only for one case. The second case requires the similar approach.

1. Extract event handler function to separate method. For example `onUnhandledRejection`.
2. Mock `Logger.prototype.onUnhandledRejection`.
3. Create `Logger` instance.
4. Execute `window.dispatchEvent('unhandledrejection')`.
5. Check if `instance.onUnhandledRejection` was called.

Steps above allow you to check if you have set correct event handlers. Next, you can test `onUnhandledRejection` as any other class method.